# Modsecurity: How can I consolidate all SecRules to ignore aparameter

Tags: mod-security, whitelist

How can I consolidate all or any secrule to ignore a parameter with modsecurity?

I have a form that will always flag as XSS, unfortunately, my rule list is getting rather large as the site grows.

I now have a list of about 10 or so rules ignoring the parameter bacon.tuna

```
SecRuleUpdateTargetById 981176 !ARGS:/^bacon.tuna/
```

I noticed that one of those rules wasn't white listed came back up and I was curious to know if there was a way to make this simpler.

Maybe something like `SecRuleUpdateTargetById * !ARGS:/^bacon.tuna/` ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I doubt your parameter is named bacon.tuna. What is the _real_ parameter name? What rules are you setting off?

Comment: The parameter is custom to our site. The parameter is event.save

Comment: The param is taking in a form that has html which will flag as xss of course . but I have been trying to whitelist these forms

Comment: Your example rule doesn't check ARGS. You may be able to use `SecRuleUpdateTargetByTag` if they share a common tag.

Comment: This worked! Make an answer for this to accept credit for it.